# Row-based calculation of current sum of multiple columns in time series

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyverse

I am querying a database that has the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2),
             type = c("A", "B1", "B2", "A", "B1"),
             date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-23 6:00", "2018-07-23 6:12", 
                                 "2018-07-23 6:25", "2018-07-23 10:00", 
                                 "2018-07-23 10:30")),
             value = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 4))

  id type                date value
1  1    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     5
2  2   B1 2018-07-23 06:12:00     2
3  2   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     3
4  1    A 2018-07-23 10:00:00     7
5  2   B1 2018-07-23 10:30:00     4
```

The `date` variable represents when changes have been made to the data base. My goal is to reformat the dataframe in a way that allows me to identify the sum of the entries of the `value` variable for every row / new entry. In calculating the sums, the value for all categories in the `type` variable needs to be replaced whenever a new entry for that category occurs.

Here is the expected output:

```
  id type                date value combined_value
1  1    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     5              5
2  2   B1 2018-07-23 06:12:00     2              7
3  2   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     3             10
4  1    A 2018-07-23 10:00:00     7             12
5  2   B1 2018-07-23 10:30:00     4             14
```

The value for `combined_value`in the first three rows is simply a sum of `value`, In the fourth row, the value for `type == "A"` changes from 5 to 7 and has to replaced, but the values for `type == "B1"` and `type == "B2"` remain constant. `type == "B1"` changes in the fifth row, however, and accordingly has to be replaced in the calculating the sum in `combined_value`.

So far, I have been successful in calculating the sums for predefined points in time using a combination of `group_by()`, `filter()` and `summarise()`. However, I want to be able to trace all changes that have been made in over a year using a data frame that stores all entries in rows and contains information on the respective current sum taken over the various categories in `type`.

**Edit**: The solution provided by @jaySf works on the provided example data. My actual dataset however has a large number of groups for which the current sum needs to be calculated. Here is an updated data frame reflecting the structure, with `id` denoting the group indices:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             type = c("A", "B1", "B2", "A", "B1", 
                      "A", "A", "B2", "B3", "A"),
             date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-23 6:00", "2018-07-23 6:12", 
                                 "2018-07-23 6:25", "2018-07-23 10:00", 
                                 "2018-07-23 10:30")),
             value = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7))
```

Correspondingly, the expected output would be:

```
   id type                date value combined_value
1   1    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     5              5
2   1   B1 2018-07-23 06:12:00     2              7
3   1   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     3             10
4   1    A 2018-07-23 10:00:00     7             12
5   1   B1 2018-07-23 10:30:00     4             14
6   2    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     3              3
7   2    A 2018-07-23 06:12:00     5              5
8   2   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     1              6
9   2   B3 2018-07-23 10:00:00     2              8
10  2    A 2018-07-23 10:30:00     7             10
```

I tried `tapply` to acount for my groups, but couldn't get the code to work.

Comment: See my edit if it fits to your needs now. I've tested it with three id groups and should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a base R solution.

We could add up row-wisely the latest values for each `type` based on the `date` column. After that we actualize each `id` group.

```
actualizeIDs <- function(df) sapply(
  lapply(seq_along(df[, 1]), 
         function(y) {
           d <- df[1:y, ]
           sapply(unique(d$type), 
                  function(x) {
                    d[d$type == x & d$date == max(d$date[d$type == x]), "value"]
                  }
           )
         }
  ), sum)

actualizeGroups <- function(df) {
  if (length(which(duplicated(df[, -4]))) > 0) {
    warning("Duplicated measurements, using latest row-number.")
  df <- df[- which(duplicated(df[, -4], fromLast=TRUE)), ]
  }
  df <- with(df, df[order(id, date), ])
  df$combined_value <- matrix(sapply(unique(df$id), 
                                     function(x) {
                                       actualizeIDs(df[df$id == x, ])
                                     }))
  return(df)
}
```

***Yielding***

```
> actualizeGroups(df)
   id type                date value combined_value
1   1    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     5              5
2   1   B1 2018-07-23 06:12:00     2              7
3   1   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     3             10
4   1    A 2018-07-23 10:00:00     7             12
5   1   B1 2018-07-23 10:30:00     4             14
6   2    A 2018-07-23 06:00:00     3              3
7   2    A 2018-07-23 06:12:00     5              5
8   2   B2 2018-07-23 06:25:00     1              6
9   2   B3 2018-07-23 10:00:00     2              8
11  2    A 2018-07-23 10:30:00     8             11
Warning message:
In actualizeGroups(df) : Duplicated measurements, using latest row-number.
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 type = c("A", "B1", "B2", "A", "B1", 
                          "A", "A", "B2", "B3", "A", "A"),
                 date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-23 6:00", "2018-07-23 6:12", 
                                     "2018-07-23 6:25", "2018-07-23 10:00", 
                                     "2018-07-23 10:30", "2018-07-23 6:00", 
                                     "2018-07-23 6:12", "2018-07-23 6:25", 
                                     "2018-07-23 10:00", "2018-07-23 10:30", 
                                     "2018-07-23 10:30")),
                 value = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 8))
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution works nicely. I neglected to mention my dataset has a multiple groups for which the current sum needs to be calculated. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to account for these groups within the `apply` family of functions

Comment: @tifu See my edit if it fits to your needs now. I've tested it with three `id` groups and should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me a lot. The only remaining issue is that there are occurences where two entries have been saved at the same time so the functions still do not work on my dataset, but this I can figure out by myself.

Comment: Might have been a tad too confident. After some research, the remaining issues occur when rows of the same type have been made at the exact same time. In these cases, the `actualizeIDs` function throws an error (`invalid 'type' (list) of argument`), presumably because `max(d$date[d$type == x])` no longer leads to an unambigious result. My intuitive solution was to replace the `date` column with consecutive integers grouped by `id`, but that did not do the trick. @jaySf might I ask how you think this problem might be solved?

Comment: @tifu I see your problem. Different measurements at the exact same time don't make much sense to me, though. Depends on how you want to handle such cases. Perhaps taking the latest row-number, calculate the mean, the median, the max, the min?

Comment: Yes it doesn't make much sense and I'll have to talk to IT to find out how this can even happen. The latest row number is what I need and I thought I had separated those entries by replacing `date` with `group_by(id) %>% mutate(rowno = row_number())`. Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: I've implemented a duplicate test and a warning message. Should fit now.

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks so much for your effort, @jaySf!